How to make the white background of a jpg image transparent using Python?
My JPG image has a white background around it. I don't want to change the image itself, I just want to make the white background transparent.Here is the code:
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# 文件路径和文件名
path = "images/"
filename = "demo.jpg"
input_filepath = path + filename
output_filepath = path + "demo_transparent.png"

# 读取彩色图像
img = cv2.imread(input_filepath)

# 转换为灰度图像
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# 定义阈值
thresh = 250

# 阈值化图像
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# 查找图像中的轮廓
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# 创建一个全白的掩码
mask = np.ones_like(gray) * 255

# 绘制找到的轮廓，填充内部区域
cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, 0, thickness=cv2.FILLED)

# 反转掩码
mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

# 将原图转换为包含透明通道的图像
rgba = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

# 遍历图像像素，将白色背景变为透明
height, width = mask.shape
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        if mask[y, x] == 255 and np.all(rgba[y, x][:3] == 255):
            rgba[y, x][3] = 0  # 设置Alpha通道为0（透明）

# 将结果保存为PNG图像
result = Image.fromarray(rgba)
result.save(output_filepath)

print(f"Processed image saved at: {output_filepath}")


This code does help me make the white background around the image transparent, but it also changes the color of the image. I would like to ask how to keep the original image? Thanks.
I tried asking ChatGTP to help me out but he is no smarter than a human.

Can you post white background image?

https://www.google.com/search?q=4804888804127&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiGu8H7qJeGAxUU-gIHHXqFDs8Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=4804888804127&gs_lp=EgNpbWciDTQ4MDQ4ODg4MDQxMjdI8QxQ7gpY7gpwAHgAkAEAmAH8AaABjAOqAQUwLjEuMbgBA8gBAPgBAYoCC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwgIEECMYJ4gGAQ&sclient=img&ei=8a5IZsb-LZT0i-gP-oq6-Aw&bih=565&biw=1171&prmd=ivnbz&hl=zh-CN#imgrc=OFp4-SOj6gCIAM, image url

Luckily code has comments...

You say you want to change the background and not change the image and use jpg. I didn't even know that jpg supports transparency.

@MadPhysicist JPEG definitely does not support transparency, never has.  It will need to be saved in a different format such as PNG.  Unfortunately that will make it larger.

The proper solution is to not needlessly mix OpenCV and PIL.
You started with OpenCV. Stick with OpenCV. You aren't using PIL for anything but saving the image. OpenCV does that just as well.
This is all you need:
cv.imwrite(output_filepath, rgba)

Note that your rgba array is actually BGRA-ordered, not RGBA-ordered. The name will confuse.

your for-loop can be turned into a single numpy operation.
set_alpha_mask = (mask == 255) & np.all(rgba[:,:,:3] == 255, axis=2)
rgba[set_alpha_mask, 3] = 0


Your problem was that OpenCV doesn't use RGB, it uses BGR (blue, green, red). The image becomes incorrect already at the stage
img = cv2.imread(input_filepath)

So you need to add
b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
img = cv2.merge([r, g, b])

Here is the finished code of your project
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

path = "images/"
filename = "demo.jpg"

input_filepath = path + filename
output_filepath = path + "demo_transparent.png"

img = cv2.imread(input_filepath)
b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
img = cv2.merge([r, g, b])

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = 250
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

mask = np.ones_like(gray) * 255

cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, 0, thickness=cv2.FILLED)

mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
rgba = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

height, width = mask.shape
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        if mask[y, x] == 255 and np.all(rgba[y, x][:3] == 255):
            rgba[y, x][3] = 0
            
result = Image.fromarray(rgba)
result.save(output_filepath)

print(f"Processed image saved at: {output_filepath}")


Where in the OP's code do you see a dependency on the channel order?

If you don't do the transformation I'm talking about, then Python will expect channel B in place of channel R, and channel R in place of channel B.

That is definitely true, but what part of the OP's code fails because of it?  That's the part I don't see.

This code does not fail. He was just making an image with the wrong colors. If your program gives an error, then make sure that the image is "demo.jpg" is located in the "images" folder, and that python file is located next to that folder

But I can say that the root of the error is the string "img = cv2.imread(input_filepath)", which itself incorrectly defines the color channels.

Never mind, I finally figured it out.  The input uses OpenCV and the output uses PIL.Image, which differ in their channel order.  You need to make a conversion at some point to get the correct output.  And it doesn't matter where you do the conversion, it could be at the input as you stated or it could be just before you save it.

Right. I was talking specifically about the input, because you can leave it and result = Image.fromarray(rgba);result.save(output_filepath), as a result of which the image will already be incorrect.

OP mixed opencv and PIL, which have different assumptions about channel order. cvtColor requires BGR order. you broke that.
